# How do I create a hash of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Based on my current understanding of hashes in Perl, I would expect this code to print "hello world." It instead prints nothing.

```
%a=();

%b=();
$b{str} = "hello";  
$a{1}=%b;

$b=();
$b{str} = "world";
$a{2}=%b;

print "$a{1}{str}  $a{2}{str}";
```

I assume that a hash is just like an array, so why can't I make a hash contain another?

Comment: The short and sweet of why this doesn't work is that because, basically, a hash or an array can only contain scalar values, and hashes are not scalars.  However, hash references are. :)  The answers below have some good links about why this is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should always use "use strict;" in your program.
2. Use references and anonymous hashes.

```
use strict;use warnings;
my %a;

my %b;
$b{str} = "hello";  
$a{1}={%b};

%b=();
$b{str} = "world";
$a{2}={%b};

print "$a{1}{str}  $a{2}{str}";
```

`{%b}` creates reference to copy of hash `%b`. You need copy here because you empty it later.

Comment: @Mike: Using strictures should be *standard*, not the special case.

Comment: @ether I realize that now, I'm learning Perl and just discovered *strict*

Answer (score 6):

Hashes of hashes are tricky to get right the first time. In this case

```
$a{1} = { %b };
...
$a{2} = { %b };
```

will get you where you want to go.

See [`perldoc perllol`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perllol) for the gory details about two-dimensional data structures in Perl.

Comment: `perldoc perllol` is all arrays, all the time, I think. `perldoc perldsc` moves into more complicated scenarios (and includes hashes). I also highly recommend `perldoc perlreftut` for anyone new to references in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  hash keys can only be associated with a scalar, not a hash.  To do what you want, you need to use references.

Rather than re-hash (heh) how to create multi-level data structures, I suggest you read perlreftut.  perlref is more complete, but it's a bit overwhelming at first.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about perldsc.  I had to look at perlref to remember that perlreftut existed. :-)  I think I should re-familiarize myself with the docs.

Comment: @davidwall Reviewing the docs is always good, but the tutorials section in particular is easy to forget but not to be missed. I especially remember liking `perlre`, `perlreftut`, `perldsc`, `perlopentut`, `perltoot` (maybe this one is out of date or out of touch with current best practices about OO in Perl - not sure) and `perlstyle`.

Answer (score 2):

Mike, Alexandr's is the right answer.

Also a tip. If you are just learning hashes perl has a module called Data::Dumper that can pretty-print your data structures for you, which is really handy when you'd like to check what values your data structures have.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%a);
```

when you print this it shows

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'str' => 'hello'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'str' => 'world'
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl likes to flatten your data structures.  That's often a good thing...for example, `(@options, "another option", "yet another")` ends up as one list.

If you really mean to have one structure inside another, the inner structure needs to be a reference.  Like so:

```
%a{1} = { %b };
```

The braces denote a hash, which you're filling with values from %b, and getting back as a reference rather than a straight hash.

You could also say

```
$a{1} = \%b;
```

but that makes changes to %b change $a{1} as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create 1000 employees records for testing a T&A system. The employee records were stored in a hash where the key was the employee's identity number, and the value was a hash of their name, date of birth, and date of hire etc. Here's how...

```
# declare an empty hash
%employees = ();

# add each employee to the hash
$employees{$identity} = {gender=>$gender, forename=>$forename, surname=>$surname, dob=>$dob, doh=>$doh};

# dump the hash as CSV
foreach $identity ( keys %employees ){
    print "$identity,$employees{$identity}{forename},$employees{$identity}{surname}\n";
}
```